# Can I add AnimationListener for Fragment translation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation

I apply some animation for fragment translation. Can I add an animation listener to detect the animation start/end event?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can if you override `onCreateAnimation()` (or `onCreateAnimator()` if you are using 3.0+ fragments...both allow listeners) inside of your custom fragment to provide the animations rather than using the custom animation methods of `FragmentTransaction`:

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation (int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    Animation anim;
    if (enter) {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    } else {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
    });

    return anim;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example to explain how to use it?

Comment: What the `transit` parameter is used for?

Comment: If you have set the transition style of your `FragmentTransaction`, this value will update to reflect the requested animation type.

Comment: By this solution I can give animation to the current fragment which is going to be open. But I also want to give exit animation to the fragment from which current will open. How would i achieve it?

Like FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit).

Comment: @RohanPatel did you got solution for `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)` ??